# SQLite: Entity Framework 6 - Wrong DbProviderFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, database-connection

I'm going bonkers with this.

I have a standard C# console application, with EF 6.1.3 and SQLite 1.0.97.0. I've set up my app.config to connect to the SQLite database using standard ADO, which works:

```
static void StandardConnection()
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudioContext"].ConnectionString);
        db.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But for the love of me, I can't get EF to connect to this database. I have tried every single solution I could read up on, but every time I try to connect, I find the DBProviderFactory always points to `{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory}`. It is driving me insane.

[image]

Following, my DbContext class:

```
public class SqliteContext: DbContext
{
    public SqliteContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudioContext"].ConnectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SqliteContext>(null);
    }
}
```

I don't want code first enabled, so disabled it here as this is off an existing application, being ported from PHP to C# and we have to work with the database as it is currently.

The code that's trying to connect:

```
static void EntityFrameworkConnection()
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new SqliteContext())
        {
            if (db.Database.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Open();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Very basic, open an instance of the context, check the state and connect if closed, this step is not required as I understand that EF will open the connection, if closed, when doing something like a save, for example, I'm just trying to get the DB to connect.

My app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudioContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\studio.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.97.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.97.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.97.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.97.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the provider entry for SQL Server from your `app.config`?

Comment: it defaults back to SqlClient, weird I know. I have isolated this into a web application, and it works, 100%, SQLite connects and we can do what we need to, but we need the connection working in a console application, and for the love of me, I can't :(

Comment: Are the NuGet-Packages for System.Data.SQLite.LINQ, SQLite.EF6 etc. already on the right version? 1.0.97.0 has only been out for a few days, and we have machines that still get 1.0.96 over NuGet, which would lead to version mismatches. Are you using the Designer add-ons over GAC, and are they already on the right version? Did you make the database using the same version as you are using now?

Comment: @fk2 looked into this as well. not using Designer add-ons as they generally don't work. sqlitedb is version 3, we verified this so no changes there. all assemblies updated to 1.0.97.0 as per the latest nuget, unless I'm missing something. the exact same code works in an isolated MVC 5 application on the same machine. it is just the console application that is not working :(

Comment: Sadly just saying it's SQLite3 doesn't really work - 1.0.97.0 is a breaking release (well, the website says "possibly" breaking: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki) so you should probably recreate the DB just in case. The docs for system.data.sqlite are bonkers, and if they write something like "possibly incompatible change" something behind the scenes is probably gonna salt the earth behind them...

Comment: @fk2 i get, you're right. i'll try .88.0 first and see if it still works, if so will stick to that.